# DateTime.AddDays or new DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, performance, datetime, stopwatch

I'm creating a list of a month's worth of dates.  I'm wondering what will be more efficient

```
List<DateTime> GetDates(DateTime StartDay) {
  List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
  int TotalDays=StartDay.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1).Day;
  for (int i=1; i<TotalDays; i++) {
    dates.Add(new DateTime(StartDay.Year, StartDay.Month, i));
  }
  return dates;
}
```

or

```
List<DateTime> GetDates(DateTime StartDay) {
  List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
  DateTime NextMonth = StartDay.AddMonths(1);
  for (DateTime curr=StartDay; !curr.Equals(NextMonth); curr=curr.AddDays(1)) {
    dates.Add(curr);
  }
  return dates;
}
```

basically, is new DateTime() or DateTime.addDays more efficient.

UPDATE:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw=new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
  long t1, t2, total;
  List<DateTime> l;
  DateTime begin = DateTime.Now;
  total = 0L;
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    sw.Start();
    l = GetDates(begin);
    sw.Stop();


    sw.Stop();
    t1 = sw.ElapsedTicks;
    sw.Reset();
    sw.Start();

    l = GetDates2(begin);
    sw.Stop();
    t2=sw.ElapsedTicks;
    total +=  t1- t2;

    Console.WriteLine("Test {0} : {1} {2} : {3}", i,t1,t2, t1- t2);
  }
  Console.WriteLine("Total: {0}", total);

  Console.WriteLine("\n\nDone");
  Console.ReadLine();
}

static List<DateTime> GetDates(DateTime StartDay) {
  List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
  int TotalDays=StartDay.AddMonths(10000).AddDays(-1).Day;
  for (int i=1; i<TotalDays; i++) {
    dates.Add(new DateTime(StartDay.Year, StartDay.Month, i));
  }
  return dates;
}


static List<DateTime> GetDates2(DateTime StartDay) {
  List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
  DateTime NextMonth = StartDay.AddMonths(10000);
  for (DateTime curr=StartDay; !curr.Equals(NextMonth); curr=curr.AddDays(1)) {
    dates.Add(curr);
  }
  return dates;
}
```

```
Test 0 : 2203229 63086205 : -60882976
Test 1 : 63126483 102969090 : -39842607
Test 2 : 102991588 93487982 : 9503606
Test 3 : 93510942 69439034 : 24071908
Test 4 : 69465137 70660555 : -1195418
Test 5 : 70695702 68224849 : 2470853
Test 6 : 68248593 63555492 : 4693101
Test 7 : 63578536 65086357 : -1507821
Test 8 : 65108190 64035573 : 1072617
Test 9 : 64066128 64933449 : -867321
Total: -62484058

Done
```

results are consistently negative... way negative, so, looks like the constructor and integer test is the more efficient method.

Comment: Just to note: the first code example won't work -- DateTime.Day returns the day of the month. Use a TimeSpan instead if you want that quantity.

Comment: right, so, for january 1, 2009, it'd add a month (Feb 1, 2009), subtract a day (Jan 31, 2009) and then give me the day portion (31) which is what i want.

Comment: Very curious results. :Starts Digging:

Comment: From the context, StartDay cannot be assumed to start on the first of the month. If I start on the 5th of the month, I end up on the 4th using that code. If you're always on month boundaries, I would suggest using the DateTime.DaysInMonth() static function.

Comment: Ah, got it now - if you modify the second test so that it is exactly like the first test, but replace `dates.Add(new DateTime(StartDay.Year, StartDay.Month, i))` with `dates.Add(StartDay.AddDays(1))`, the second version performs roughly twice as fast. (The first test run will be slower than any subsequent run, whichever algorithm you use.)

Comment: You should really use System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch for timing

Comment: re: Jeff Sternal: Changed it and I am finding the same thing.  Didn't realize that the datetime comparison would be so much slower... well... i'll go with the .addDays(1)

Comment: I also will probably change it to DaysInMonth.. I'm sure that's much more efficient than adding a month, subtracting a day, and then returning the day portion

Comment: in case anyone cares, DaysInMonth is ~4X faster than Addmonth, SubtractDay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really hard to imagine a case in which this would make a significant difference, but Reflector shows that the `AddDays` technique should be more efficient.

Compare the core logic of `AddDays` (from `Add(Double, Int32)`)

```
long num = (long) ((value * scale) + ((value >= 0.0) ? 0.5 : -0.5));
if ((num <= -315537897600000L) || (num >= 0x11efae44cb400L)) {
    // Throw omitted
}
return this.AddTicks(num * 0x2710L);
```

To the core logic of the  `DateTime(int, int, int)` constructor (from `DateToTicks`):

```
if (((year >= 1) && (year <= 0x270f)) && ((month >= 1) && (month <= 12)))
{
    int[] numArray = IsLeapYear(year) ? DaysToMonth366 : DaysToMonth365;
    if ((day >= 1) && (day <= (numArray[month] - numArray[month - 1])))
    {
        int num = year - 1;
        int num2 = ((((((num * 0x16d) + (num / 4)) - (num / 100)) + (num / 400)) + numArray[month - 1]) + day) - 1;
        return (num2 * 0xc92a69c000L);
    }
}
// Throw omitted
```

`AddDays` just converts the specified number of days to the equivalent number of ticks (a long) and adds it to the existing ticks.

Creating a new `DateTime` using the year/month/day constructor requires many more calculations. That constructor has to check whether the specified year is a leap year, allocate an array of days in each month, perform a bunch of extra operations, just to finally get the number of ticks those three numbers represent.

---

Edit: `DateTime.AddDays(int)` is faster than `new DateTime(int, int, int)`, but your first algorithm is faster than the second algorithm. This is probably because the iteration costs are much higher in the second algorithm. As you observed in your edit, this might well be because `DateTime.Equals` is more expensive than comparing integers.

Answer (score 5):

Measure it - write a test program and see which one takes less time.

Comment: then report your results here :)

Answer (score 3):

I believe datetime operations return new datetime structures so you will be creating new instances either way.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx

Comment: You believe?  Wouldn't it have just been better to quote it?  "This method does not change the value of this DateTime. Instead, a new DateTime is returned whose value is the result of this operation."

Comment: Moreover, even though they both create new DateTime instances, the two constructors involve very different algorithms.

Comment: Your critiquing my choice of words?  I felt it more polite the way I wrote it and to include a link.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are doing some financial processing then I would worry more about readability than performance here.  Only start worrying about performance somewhere like here if it's a proven bottleneck.

Comment: +1, this is definitely the most important advice. I feel a little silly having dug so deeply into this. D:

Answer (score 2):

Since they both do the same thing in the end, there isn't much of a difference.

If you're looking for efficiency, just use ticks.  All (that I've seen) calls in DateTime are eventually converted into ticks before any math gets done.

Comment: Though they both create new instances, they definitely do not do the same thing.

Comment: They do the same thing **in the end**, and what difference there is between the two methods **isn't much**.  Don't be anal, guy.

Comment: Not just that, but while analing out about the first line, you completely ignored the second, which states the truth--the most efficient way to deal with the DateTime structure is to work in ticks only.

Comment: Yikes, I submit. I agree with the second part.

Comment: MY ANGER HAS BEEN AROUSED.  MUST SMASH.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working test program, with the algorithms implemented so that they can actually be compared (they still need work, though):

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IList<DateTime> l1, l2;
            DateTime begin = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);

            Stopwatch timer1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                l1 = GetDates(begin);
            timer1.Stop();

            Stopwatch timer2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                l2 = GetDates2(begin);
            timer2.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("new DateTime: {0}\n.AddDays: {1}",
                timer1.ElapsedTicks, timer2.ElapsedTicks);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static IList<DateTime> GetDates(DateTime StartDay)
        {
            IList<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();

            int TotalDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(StartDay.Year, StartDay.Month);

            for (int i = 0; i < TotalDays; i++)
                dates.Add(new DateTime(StartDay.Year, StartDay.Month, i + 1));

            return dates;
        }


        static IList<DateTime> GetDates2(DateTime StartDay)
        {
            IList<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();

            DateTime NextMonth = StartDay.AddMonths(1);

            for (DateTime curr = StartDay; !curr.Equals(NextMonth); curr = curr.AddDays(1))
                dates.Add(curr);

            return dates;
        }
    } // class
```

Output (I added the commas):

```
new DateTime: 545,307,375
.AddDays: 180,071,512
```

These results seem pretty clear to me, though honestly I thought they'd be a lot closer.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mark.  Test both methods yourself and see which one is faster.  Use the Stopwatch class to get accurate timings of how long each method takes to run. My first guess is that since both end up creating new structures anyway, that any speed difference will be negligible.  Also, with only generating a month's worth of dates (31 days maximum), I don't think either method will be that much slower than the other.  Perhaps is you you were generating thousands or millions of dates, it would make a difference, but for 31 dates, it's probably premature optimization.